# Is there a Firefox addon that helps me finding the next line (in next screen) after hitting space bar?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I started to read websites screen by screen - without scrolling all the time as I did before.

However, when hitting the space key (or page down) to scroll I have problems finding the line again, to continue reading.

I would love to have a plugin / feature that - after hitting the space - highlights the next line (next line after last visible line of last screen).

Do you know some helper like that? Or do you have any tips on this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Scroll Highlight.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scroll-highlight/

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was searching for! It has some minor issues (e.g. incorrect position when developer bar is visible) but works so far.